PostgreSQL has stopped using index for large IN query?
I've got a large table (~2.2 billion rows), the table structure is basic:
    Column    |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |             Default              | Storage | Compression | Stats target | Description
--------------+---------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------+---------+-------------+--------------+-------------
 Id           | bigint  |           | not null | generated by default as identity | plain   |             |              |
 ItemId       | uuid    |           | not null |                                  | plain   |             |              |
 StartUtc     | integer |           | not null |                                  | plain   |             |              |
 EndUtc       | integer |           | not null |                                  | plain   |             |              |
 Price        | integer |           | not null |                                  | plain   |             |              |
Indexes:
    "PK_PriceHistoryEntry" PRIMARY KEY, btree ("Id")
    "IX_PriceHistoryEntry_ItemId" btree ("ItemId") CLUSTER

All the queries are done against the ItemId column, in the form:
SELECT "ItemId", "StartUtc", "EndUtc", "Price" FROM "PriceHistoryEntry" WHERE "ItemId" IN (...array of guids)

The table isn't partitioned because every select query would need to reach across every partition, queries are never done only in certain date ranges, always full history.
The general insertion method is once a week 10-20 million price history entries are inserted, the table is reclustered on the ItemId index and then selects are highly performant for our purposes (~100ms for the average search we do, which is approx 250-400 GUIDs in the IN criteria returning ~50k rows).
In development I tested this with up to 5 billion rows and up to 1000 GUIDs in the IN criteria, it was always fast. It had been running perfect for over a year, but today PostgreSQL has stopped using the index when the IN contains more than 400 GUIDs and I can't work out why, index plan for 400 GUIDs:
Index Scan using "IX_PriceHistoryEntry_ItemId" on public."PriceHistoryEntry"  (cost=0.58..32570020.41 rows=23433784 width=28) (actual time=11.355..110.863 rows=160503 loops=1)
   Output: "ItemId", "StartUtc", "EndUtc", "Price"
   Index Cond: ("PriceHistoryEntry"."ItemId" = ANY ('{ac5aa227-8787-46fc-b34d-47017edc7d1f,*cut 398 guids*,16923b11-30b7-4311-bc54-3b2b1da314d0}'::uuid[]))
   Buffers: shared hit=828 read=2550
   I/O Timings: shared read=79.971
 Planning Time: 0.314 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 4
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 0.234 ms, Inlining 0.064 ms, Optimization 6.114 ms, Emission 4.823 ms, Total 11.235 ms
 Execution Time: 115.573 ms
(11 rows)

Time: 116.586 ms

but if you use 401 GUIDs:
 Gather  (cost=1000.99..32292650.29 rows=23734217 width=28) (actual time=232.393..55599.947 rows=161872 loops=1)
   Output: "ItemId", "StartUtc", "EndUtc", "Price"
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2
   Buffers: shared hit=7543 read=17088587
   I/O Timings: shared read=48381.022
   ->  Parallel Seq Scan on public."PriceHistoryEntry"  (cost=0.99..29918228.59 rows=9889257 width=28) (actual time=227.890..51672.274 rows=53957 loops=3)
         Output: "ItemId", "StartUtc", "EndUtc", "Price"
         Filter: ("PriceHistoryEntry"."ItemId" = ANY ('{bff9de7e-7f35-4f5d-88c5-2c342806d69b,*cut 399 guids*,618ce691-c8f0-46b2-8fd1-96a404bdda71}'::uuid[]))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 683791228
         Buffers: shared hit=7543 read=17088587
         I/O Timings: shared read=48381.022
         Worker 0:  actual time=329.642..50237.693 rows=54262 loops=1
           JIT:
             Functions: 4
             Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
             Timing: Generation 0.238 ms, Inlining 45.205 ms, Optimization 4.210 ms, Emission 3.867 ms, Total 53.520 ms
           Buffers: shared hit=2368 read=5516111
           I/O Timings: shared read=15615.749
         Worker 1:  actual time=122.393..49195.649 rows=52913 loops=1
           JIT:
             Functions: 4
             Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
             Timing: Generation 0.240 ms, Inlining 45.364 ms, Optimization 4.256 ms, Emission 3.936 ms, Total 53.796 ms
           Buffers: shared hit=2447 read=5377318
           I/O Timings: shared read=15380.362
 Planning Time: 0.396 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 12
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 0.767 ms, Inlining 90.645 ms, Optimization 16.254 ms, Emission 13.825 ms, Total 121.492 ms
 Execution Time: 55604.845 ms
(32 rows)

Time: 55606.114 ms (00:55.606)

As I say, when developing this I tested it extensively with up to 5 billion rows and 1000+ GUIDs in the IN criteria, which is significantly more than is currently in the database and I never encountered this issue.
I've tried:

Reclustering the table
Re-indexing IX_PriceHistoryEntry_ItemId
VACUUM ANALYZE on the table
VACUUM FULL on the table
Rebuilding the whole table with pg_repack

It still refuses to use the index now. Any idea what has happened, how to fix it, and how to make sure it never happens again?
If I disable seq scan (set enable_seqscan = off;) it uses the index correctly and returns the results in 100ms... rather than the 55 seconds it takes when PostgreSQL uses the plan it thinks is best. Disabling seqscan seems to be not recommended though, if I lower random_page_cost it will use the index for slightly bigger queries, but for a particularly large IN it still uses a sequence scan. I need to ensure it never uses a seq scan as it will never be faster for this table.

I'm guessing that ndistinct for "ItemId" has gotten deranged.  You can check it out in the pg_stats view to see.
This often happens for columns on which the table is clustered, due to a flawed sampling method which is used when calculating ndistinct.
If that is the problem, you can override ndistinct with a more accurate manual value:
alter table "PriceHistoryEntry" alter column "ItemId" set (ndistinct = 15000000)


Ah thanks, that has become horribly wrong. The n_distinct value was 35k but there's actually 5mil distinct values. Setting n_distinct to 5mil as per your suggestion gives more realistic query plan row estimates and uses the index even for very large IN arrays. Is there a recommended way to keep this more accurate without manually altering n_distinct as the table can alter a lot? Setting statistics target to 5,000 n_distinct is 1mil, closer, but at the expense of slower vacuums. Half tempted just to local enable_seqscan false in the transaction for these queries but docs say not to.

There have been some proposals to fix the sampling method, but they have not gotten any traction so far.  Increasing the target might work weakly; having a larger biased sample can be better than a smaller biased sample, but isn't the same thing as an unbiased sample.  You could set up a scheduled job to compute a true value select count(distinct ...), and then plug that into the manual setting.  There is nothing wrong with turning off enable_seqscan, as long as you can do it in a focused way for this query and then remember to reset it afterwards.

@jjanes thanks again, both of those options are viable, I can cheaply calculate the number of distinct ItemIds from another table and update n_distinct via that. As a temporary measure I'll go with the easier option of locally disabling enable_seqscan for the transaction scope that executes the IN query because I always want that to use the index. I wasn't sure if there was a downside to disabling enable_seqscan but it should be ok as long as I only do it for single queries that I specifically want to use the index?
